# OneToMany Extenstion is getting deleted

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

Why do my order extensions get deleted after editing the order.

I have an OneToMany extension to the order definition:

```
 $collection->add(
      (new OneToManyAssociationField(
        'example',
        ExampleDefinition::class,
        'order_id'
      ))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(), new Inherited())
 );
```

And my extension definition:

```
return new FieldCollection([
      (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
      (new FkField('order_id', 'orderId', OrderDefinition::class)),
      (new ReferenceVersionField(OrderDefinition::class, 'order_version_id'))->addFlags(new Required()),
      (new StringField('value', 'value'))->addFlags(new Required()),
      (new ManyToOneAssociationField('order', 'order_id', OrderDefinition::class, 'id'))->addFlags(new ReverseInherited('example')),
]);
```

I add my data like that

```
$values = array_map(static function ($value) use($event) {
    return [
      'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
      'value' => $value['value'],
      'orderId' => getOrder()->getId(),
       'order_version_id' => getOrder()->getVersionId()
    ];
}, $new_values);

$this->orderRepository->update([
    [
        'id' => $orderId,
        'example' => $values
    ]
], $event->getSalesChannelContext()->getContext());
```

The array values is correct (I trucated some stuff here).

When I open the order in Administration my fields are there (I added a custom view in the order detail base view)

When I click edit on the order my order_version_id is updated but when I save or cancel the edit my extension values are deleted from DB.

This is run during migration:

```
$this->updateInheritance($connection, 'order', 'example');
$this->registerIndexer($connection, 'Swag.InheritanceIndexer');
```

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening due to the process of versionizing the order when it is edited. You might have to re-set the extension when a new version of an order is created in the editing process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74378781/8556259) for a more detailed explanation of the process.